# Скачивание файла с cURL

Tags: php, curl

Доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться. Скачиваю файл таким способом:

```
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/file.torrent","w");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $torrentUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_POST['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($fp);
curl_close($ch);
```

Вовсе не ручаюсь за адекватность кода, но суть проблемы вот в чем: на одном хостинге он не работает (файл создается, но остается пустым), а на домашнем сервере (Денвер) - работает, файл и создается и наполняется требуемым содержимым. При этом другие функции cURL работают исправно, проблема только со скачиванием файла. Какие действия стоит предпринять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема разрешилась. Сервер не работал с `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);`, пришлось вручную получать редиректы с помощью заголовков и регулярных выражений, затем отправлять cURL по ним.